# Apache: rewrite or redirect?

Tags: apache-httpd, variable, url

I need to redirect an URL with a variable, eg.

`http://www.mydomain.com/foo/55555` should go to `http://www.mydomain.com/bar/55555` where `55555` is a variable number.

Do I need to use *redirect* or *rewrite*?

Comment: You need a rewrite to handle the variable. You need a redirect if you want users who visit foo, to go to bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

here's a `Rewrite`Rule that implements the redirect (`[R]`)

```
  RewriteRule ^/foo/([0-9]*)$ /bar?q=$1 [R]
```

if you are using `.htaccess` to add your rewrite rules, you might want to make this local to the `/foo` directory, so put the following into `foo/.htaccess`:

```
  RewriteRule ^([0-9]*)$ /bar&q=$1 [R]
```

Comment: I have insert this rule  `RewriteRule http://www.mydomain.com/foo/([0-9]*)$ http://www.mydomain.com/bar?q=$1 [R=301]` but don't work

Comment: @hellb0y77 so why didn't you copy my rule?

Comment: have you restarted apache? what do your logs say? if you want a decent answer, you need to provide more than "didn't work"...

Comment: @hellb0y77 btw, why do you suddenly change the rewrite rule to a different target?

Comment: From log: `[04/Mar/2015:10:55:10 +0100] "GET /foo/55555 HTTP/1.1" 404 1441 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.115 Safari/537.36"` The rule is in .htaccess

Comment: The real target is `/bar?q=$1`, to the answer i write an example

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/21632/discussion-between-umlaute-and-hellb0y77).